# php if condition has an assignment at official? site

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER BY Name";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
```

That `if` condition appears here:  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

Coming from C, C++, Java and Python, that seems wrong.  Is it a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. From [this manual site](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So, the code you linked simply checks if there was no error

Answer (score 0):

It is not a typo, it uses both an assignment and a boolean operator into a single expression.

If there is a result from the query the $result variable will be populated and the code inside if condition will be executed. In that case, you will have the result set populated to $result variable.

If it has no result the expression will reduce to a boolean false.